# Relation between the reduced Green's function and the full Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, greens-functions, lamb-shift

Let us assume that we have some Hamiltonian and we know its spectrum
$$H_0 \psi_n = E_n \psi_n .$$
We define the Green's function in as 
$$
G(x,y,E) =\sum_m \frac{\psi_m^*(x)\psi_m(y)}{E-E_m},
$$
and the reduced Green's function as
$$G'_n(x,y,E_n) =\sum_{m\neq n} \frac{\psi_m^*(x)\psi_m(y)}{E_n-E_m}.$$
Now let us assume that we have some perturbation $\delta H$. In the relativistic perturbation theory the second order correction to the energy can be calculated with the help of the reduced Green's function:
$$\Delta E_n^{(2)}=\int d^3x d^3 y \psi_n(x) \delta H(x) G'_n(x,y,E_n)\delta H(y)\psi_n(y).$$
However in the QFT, when I calculate any Feynman diagram I am forced to use the full Green's function. For example, when we calculate the Lamb shift, we use the full Green's function (see S. Weinberg,  The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol. 1 eq. 14.3.26 and 14.3.27). 
My question is: what is the relation between the perturbation theory in the relativistic quantum mechanics and the diagrammatic approach of QFT? Why in the QFT I need the full Green's function, while in the quantum mechanics I need only the reduced Green's function?

Comment: (+1) My two cents: **perhaps** its because in QFT the Hamiltonian $H_0$ has a continuous spectrum, so both Green functions ($G$ and $G'$) are actually the same.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform QFT Hamiltonian contains the discrete spectrum. However, you cannot obtain it using standard perturbation theory. The dominant contribution to the Lamb shift (Bethe log) comes from the discrete part of the spectrum.

Comment: I'm wondering, did someone find the answer for this question?